# SASS bug in calculations?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

So I'm trying to do a simple calculation in order to position an element. I have it down to a basic example that fails on the online '[Try SASS](http://sass-lang.com/try.html)' page. The first example below succeeds, whereas the second fails. The only difference is the addition or subtraction of the 12px at the end of the calculation:

**Successful**:

**SASS**:

```
$a: 955px;
$b: 8;

body {
    width: (($a/$b)/2)+12px;
}
```

**CSS**:

```
body {
width: 71.6875px; }
```

**Epic Fail?**:

**SASS**:

```
$a: 955px;
$b: 8;

body {
    width: (($a/$b)/2)-12px;
}
```

**CSS**:

```
body {
width: 59.6875px -12px; }
```

Has anybody come across this before? is this a known issue and if so is there a workaround?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bracket was missing so compiler considering that its `-ve` value :)

```
    $a: 955px;
    $b: 8;

    body {
        width: (($a/$b)/2)-(12px);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need add spaces around the `-` operator:

```
$ sass -i
>> $a: 955px
955px
>> $b: 8
8
>> (($a/$b)/2)-12px // bug
(59.6875px -12px)
>> (($a/$b)/2) - 12px // OK
47.6875px
>> ($a/$b) / 2 - 12px // Works fine too
47.6875px
```

Read the explanation of [@nex3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2518/nex3) in the issue *[Strange behavior of the subtraction operator](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/853#issuecomment-21276425)*.